# Do these examples in Bash demonstrate dynamic typing and static typing?

Tags: bash, types, programming-languages, dynamic-typing, static-typing

In Bash, what concepts in programming languages do the following examples demonstrate?

1. In the first example, the variable `bar` is first a string type with
   value `hello`, and then when it is used in an arithmetic expression,
   its value becomes `0`.  So it seems to me that the type of `bar`
   changed from string to integer.

   Does this example demonstrate the
   concepts of both **implicit type conversion** and **dynamic typing**
   (because the type of `bar` is not explicitly declared or defined,
   and changes according to the context from string to integer)?

   ```
   $ bar=hello
   $ echo $bar
   hello
   $ echo $(( bar ))
   0
   ```
2. In the second example, the variable `bbb` is declared to be integer
   type, and I gives it a value `3*8` which is `24`. Then I gives it
   `hello`, and its value changes to be `0`.

   Is `hello` a string
   value or another variable? If `hello` is a string value, then there must be type conversion from string value `hello` to integer value `0` before assigning it to variable `bbb`.

   Does this example demonstrate the concept
   of **statical typing**, because the type of `bbb` is explicitly 
   declared from the beginning and can't be changed?

   ```
   $ declare -i bbb
   $ bbb=3*8
   $ echo bbb
   24
   $ bbb=hello
   $ echo $bbb
   0
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding #1, this isn't type conversion; it's a parameter expansion.

1. `x=6; echo $((x))` produces 6. The value is a valid integer literal.
2. `x=foo; foo=6; echo $((x))` also produces 6. The value of `x` is a string that names a parameter with an integer value.
3. `unset x; echo $((x))` produces 0, because `x` is unset.
4. `x=3+5; y=bar; z=; echo $((x + y + z))` produces 0 because none of the three strings can be expanded to a non-zero integer value by any of the three previous rules.

Regarding #2, the fact that `bbb` has its integer attribute set means any value assigned to it is implicitly treated as an arithmetic expression. That is, `bbb=whatever` is equivalent to `bbb=$((whatever))`. As such, `hello` is subject to the same expansion as outlined above. Specifically,

```
$ declare -i bbb
$ bbb=hello
$ echo $bbb
0
$ hello=6
$ bbb=hello
$ echo $bbb
6
```

Comment: Thanks. 4. `x=3+5; y=bar; z=; echo $((x + y + z))` produces `8`.  Why do you say `0`?  2. `x=foo; foo=6; echo $((x))`, why can the last command trace from variable `x` to its value `foo`, and then from variable `foo` to its value `6`, instead of stopping at the value `foo` of `x`?

Comment: I dropped `x=3+5` from the example; I thought I saw that expanded to 0 in a test, but I made a mistake somewhere. Regarding the `x`/`foo` example, expansion is recursive; each time an expansion produces a string in arithmetic context, *that* string is also expanded, and the process repeats until an integer value can be derived.